# Is "Slash/Crush" damage equivalent to "Slash or Crush" damage?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

In Pillars of Eternity (the first one, PC via Steam, all DLCs owned but playing the vanilla game), one of the loading screen tips includes the following useful information:

> Any weapon that lists a damage type like "Slash or Crush" will do whatever damage type is more advantageous, usually whatever type the target is most vulnerable to.

[image: The loading screen displaying the previously quoted text hint]

This is an extremely helpful bit of advice ... except I've never seen any weapon show their damage as "slash or crush". However what I *have* seen is weapons indicating that their damage is "slash/crash".

Here is an example of a weapon, the unique great sword "Justice", which has "Slash/Pierce" damage. I've got both the weapon details and the popup description visible in this screenshot snippet. Both show that the weapon damage is listed as "19-27 Slash/Pierce Damage".

[image: A weapon that has 'slash/pierce' damage]

Are these weapons that show multiple damage types separated by the `/` character the ones that the loading screen tip were referring to? That is, does the weapon with "slash/pierce" damage displayed here do either slash *or* pierce, whichever the enemy has lower defenses against? Or does the "/" mean something else ("and"?) and the loading screen tip is referring to a different set of weapons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The slash is effectively an “Or”. The weapon will do whichever of the two types is more advantageous. The comma seperated 10% as crush, is *additional*, rather than alternative or replacement however.